# Android - Encrypting outgoing sms after sending

Tags: android, encryption, sms

I am trying to create a function which will encrypt with AES or Base64 an outgoing SMS and save it after sending it.

Is this impossible? I want to have all outgoing saved SMS encrypted in my phone.

Thanks.

Comment: The software you have in mind is not at all trivial, but there are already good applications that achieve what you want. Take a look at TextSecure: https://whispersystems.org/#encrypted_texts

Comment: Yes I know TextSecure. But I want to use this function with a different way. This is why I am trying my own

Comment: Then I recommend the book "[Cryptography Engineering](https://www.schneier.com/book-ce.html)" by Ferguson, Kohno and Schneier. It lays a good foundation of cryptographic background and the IT security mindset.